# How may I left-align (horizontally) the phrase 'whence, by rules already established for monomials' of the following?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I would like my phrase shifted `more` towards left-hand-side.

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl}
(3a+2b)^{2}&=&\{(3a)+(2b)\}^{3}\\
&=&(3a)^{3}+3(3a)^{2}(2b)+3(3a)(2b)^{2}+(2b)^{3},\\
\rlap{whence, by rules already established for monomials,}\\
&=&27a^{3}+54a^{2}b+36ab^{2}+8b^{3}.
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl}
(3a+2b)^{2}&=&\{(3a)+(2b)\}^{3}\\
&=&(3a)^{3}+3(3a)^{2}(2b)+3(3a)(2b)^{2}+(2b)^{3},\\
\shortintertext{whence, by rules already established for monomials,}
&=&27a^{3}+54a^{2}b+36ab^{2}+8b^{3}.
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is THE exact answer I looked for. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @NisalKevinKotinkaduwa even better would be to use the mathtools/ams alignments rather than eqnarray (although the ieee version is a bit better than the standard one)

Comment: @DavidCarlise
Thank you very much for the extra bit of knowledge provided. 
I use IEEEeqnarray environment for multiple equations mostly; when working with horizontal alignments. I am so used to it, hence I was inclined to use it quite often. As you have suggested, I ought to stick to the standard one; mathtools/AMS Alignments. You helped me a lot, David!